# good example of Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

is there a good example of a *source file* containing [Javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html)?

I can find lots of good examples of Javadoc on the internet, I would just like to find out the particular syntax used to create them, and assume I can pore through the source of some library somewhere but that seems like a lot of work.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

How about the JDK source code, but accessed through a 3rd party like docjar? For example, the [Collections source](https://web.archive.org/web/20190325071840/http://www.docjar.net/html/api/java/util/Collections.java.html).

That way, there's no big download.

Comment: Thats a good answer since collections where written by Josh and Neal.

Comment: My antivirus software says that docjar link is unsafe. Do you know of any other websites that feature the collections source? (I would let it slide if this wasn't a fairly high-traffic question :)

Comment: If on windows, JDK installation contains a `src.zip` file with the source code of the standard libraries.

Comment: How is it legal for a 3rd party to distribute copyrighted code? Or does the copyright allow that?

Comment: This is the main problem with external links, "Docjar.net is DOWN for everyone."

Answer (score 39):

The page [How to Write Doc Coments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html) contains a good number of good examples. One section is called [Examples of Doc Comments](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#examples) and contains quite a few usages.

Also, the [Javadoc FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137483.html) contains some more examples to illustrate the answers.

Comment: Fixed link (for now):  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

Answer (score 10):

How about the [JDK](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/) source code?

Comment: that was my obvious thought but I'd have to download the whole big mess. :-(

Comment: Chances are you already have it, since it comes with the JDK (though it's an installation option).

Answer (score 6):

I use a small set of documentation patterns:

- always documenting about thread-safety
- always documenting immutability
- javadoc with examples (like [Formatter](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html))
- @Deprecation with WHY and HOW to replace the annotated element

Comment: great hint to include HOW to replace the deprecated, thx

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at Spring framework source, it has excellent javadocs

Answer (score 4):

ANT for example - source code browsable online: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/DefaultLogger.java?view=co

To choose other files start from: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/?pathrev=761528

Answer (score 4):

The documentation of Google Guava's [EventBus](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/eventbus/package-summary.html) package and classes is a good example of Javadoc. Especially the package documentation with the quick start is well written.

Answer (score 2):

Download the sources of [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) and see how they do it.  They have good JavaDocs.

Answer (score 2):

If all your looking for is the syntax, then this may help:

[How to Write Doc Comments for the Javadoc Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html)

Comment: thanks, already aware of that though (see my question)

Comment: Duplicate answer without providing other useful info.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **Eclipse**, then you can setup your **JDK** (not *JRE*) in **Installed JREs**, and then use ***Open Type*** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>), give something like `java.util.Collections`

Comment: To add to what was said, most IDEs automatically configure javadocs and source when you configure the JDK for them to use. This does not only apply to Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

If you install a JDK and choose to install sources too, the src.zip contains the source of ALL the public Java classes.   Most of these have pretty good javadoc.