# How to put comment in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, comments

What are the dos' and don'ts in putting comment in eclipse.
And one more thing, I'm putting comments on source codes which I didn't make... and I'm having a hard time because I'm a newbie in java as well.
Any tips? Thank you :)

Comment: With putting comments you mean just adding comments to your code?

Comment: Comment in `Eclipse`? Or did you mean comment in your Java code?

Comment: And as for adding comments in files that you did not write, refer to your peers or company policy.

Comment: ctrl+shift+c is the shortcut for commenting a block of code in Eclipse, if that's what you're wondering.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079713/good-example-of-javadoc/1079765#1079765

Answer (score 2):

You can use `//` and `/* ... */` comments where you like.
There are also `/** ... */` which are JavaDoc comments,
and can be processed by external tools for generating
JavaDoc documentation.

See also: [JavaDoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-jsp-135444.html)

Eclipse or not it does not matter, this is not IDE dependent.

Comment: You may read this question on SO as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079713/good-example-of-javadoc

Answer (score 1):

Read

[10 Best Practices to Follow while writing Code Comments](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/08/code-comments-java-best-practices.html)

Comment: Link only answers are highly discouraged. Might be good as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend "Clean Code - A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship" by Robert C. Martin

You can read more information there about the following tips regarding dos' and don'ts:

- Comments Do Not Make Up for Bad Code
- Explain Yourself in Code (instead of paragraphs of comments)
- Don’t Use a Comment When You Can Use a Function or a Variable
- Good Comments
- - Legal Comments // Copyright (C) 2014
- - Informative Comments // Returns an instance of the Responder being tested.
- - Explanation of Intent // We return the first element from a list when catching an error during parse
- - Clarifcation // assertTrue(a.compareTo(a) == 0); // a == a
- - Warning of Consequences // Test purposes only
- - TODO Comments // TODO: add support for arrays
- Bad Comments
- - Mumbling // No properties files means all defaults are loaded
- - Redundant Comments // compares a with b
- - Misleading Comments // especially when code is updated and descriptive comments are left behind
- - Mandated Comments // @param title The title of the CD
- - Journal Comments // you have versioning via SVN, TFS etc, no need to write what has been modified via comments
- - Noise Comments // Default constructor
- - Commented-Out Code
- - HTML Comments
- - Too Much Information
- - Inobvious Connection // add extra 200 for header info
- - Function Headers
- - Javadocs in Nonpublic Code